# Regular Expression option "/x" (ignore option is not working in MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, regex, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have to perform find/replace functionality in my app and we decided to add ignore space option to our regular expression Mongo query. so using this code

```
 BsonRegularExpression  breg = new BsonRegularExpression (pattern,request.matchCase ? "x" : "xi");
```

It produces this string that is later be queried in mongo {/patter/xi}

But it turned out in order to use "x" and "s" option you have to use $options: format in mongoDB below is the exact quote from [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

> To use either the x option or s options, you must use the $regex operator expression with the $options operator. For example, to specify the i and the s options, you must use $options for both

So now I do not know how I can make MongoDB C# driver to produce the query that I want or if there is any other work around.

Answer (score 0):

these are two possibilities i know of.

```
var spec = new Document("someName", new MongoRegex("your regex", "x"));
yourCollection.Find(spec)
```

second approach

```
var collection = GetCollection();
    var filter = Builders<Entity>.Filter.Regex("x", new BsonRegularExpression("your regex, "i"));
    return await collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

for more info checkout on the BsonRegularExpression method check out http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/org/bson/BsonRegularExpression.html

Comment: new Document ? is a Bson document or what class it is ?

Comment: I am using map class so i did this `FieldDefinition <Step_StepContentNSDoc> StepHTML = "StepHTML";
      var filter = Builders<Step_StepContentNSDoc>.Filter.Regex(StepHTML, new BsonRegularExpression(pattern, "ix"));
      var collec = procAgg.Collection.Database.GetCollection<ProcedureNSDoc>("procedure");` but collec.find does not accept the filter only accepts mongo query